# Chatbots triggering emotions

Tags: intelligent-agent, chat-bots, emotional-intelligence

I’m a researcher and I’m currently conducting a research project. I will conduct a study where I would like to trigger different emotions using chatbots on a smartphone (e.g. on Facebook Messenger).

Are there any existing chatbots which are able to trigger different emotions intentionally (also negative ones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emotions can of course be triggered by lots of different things. I think the most rich source could well be socialbots like Mitsuku.com and Zo.ai -- Steve Worswick is the owner of Mitsuku and may be interested in helping you by doing (appropriately filtered) chat log queries. You can get him on Twitter at @Mitsuku.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have dropped some lines to steve. I also had a look at Misuku and Zo. They are very interesting and pretty intelligent but if a participant is using them for 30 minutes I think not a wide range of emotions is triggered (most of the time only positive emotions I think).

Comment: I have played around with Mitsuku and Zo. These bots are mostly triggering positive emotions. Do you know bots which are nasty or confusing (writing garbage)?

Comment: @machinery Mitsuku will get quite aggressive if you're agressive to it. If you want a mirror, check out replika.ai.

Comment: Do you know other socialbots like Mitsuku and Zo and cleverbot? I also like cleverbot because it can get pretty confusing and surprising discussions. Unfortuantely, cleverbot is not available in skype or facebook messenger.

Comment: I was supremely unimpressed with Cleverbot unfortunately -- nothing I did with it was really coherent. But the "surprise factor" yes sometimes people like that, perhaps for entertainment.

Replika.ai is a good one too. I typically talk about Jessie too but it doesn't appear to have been kept online https://www.facebook.com/JessieHumani